# In an End, how many relationships can an entity have?

Tags: java, mysql

I am designing a ERP system for a company. 
I ma now in requirement analysis phase.  I would like to know how many relationships can a SINGLE entity have?

Comment: As many as it needs to.

Comment: ... but no more.

Comment: It's only limited by the number of rows you can have in a table (and the number of tables)